# How to get Protected Excel Documents, not to give error apon opening

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, document

I have an issue any excel upload i do that is protected, gives an error saying files could be harmful then needs to open in a stand alone excel program and will not open online.

Is there a way around this?

Regards,

Comment: other than unprotecting the file, no

Answer (score 0):

See [Unsupported Features in Excel Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms496823.aspx). Included under `Features that Prevent Excel Files from Loading` is `Workbooks that use workbook and worksheet protection.`. As Eric indicated, you must unprotect the workbook/sheet to open in Excel Services/Excel Online.